# Python - Combine two bar plots in one plot window

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to add the following information

```
score_to_plot = pd.DataFrame({"a":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], 
                              "max_score":[69,77,87,99],
                              "min_score":[55, 72, 83, 94]})
```

as a "box plot", such that left side of a box starts at the `min_score` and right_side of a box ends at the `max_score`,  to the plot below. Having the scores range to be as an additional axis at the top.

Note that here bottom and top ranges are about the same, but in my actual work it is not the case and I cannot use one axis range.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="time", y="a", data={"a":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], "time":[50,70,85,150]},
            label="time_total", color="b")


sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="time", y="a", data={"a":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], "time":[20,40,65,135]},
            label="time_productive", color="b")


ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(ylabel="",
       xlabel="Productive time vs total time vs score")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

How would I do this? Thank you for help!

[image]

An approximate idea of what I want as a result

[image]

Comment: Are the grey box plots supposed to indicate `min_score` and `max_score` of `score_to_plot`?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have saved `score_to_plot` as `df`. With following addition:

```
df["widths"] = df["max_score"]-df["min_score"]
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.barh(df.a, df.widths, left=df.min_score, color="grey")
plt.xlim([0,100])
ax.legend(loc='lower left')
```

I get this. Does it help?
    [image]

Comment: The only issue -- when I try to set legend for grey score e.g label="score_achieved" in ax2.barh(df.a, df.widths, left=df.min_score, color="grey", label="score_achieved")
plt.xlim([0,100])  -- it does not appear somehow...

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. I could not combine all three legends in a single window because they are two separate plots. I think that is a minor issue: Either you can create a custom legend or there should be a way to combine two plot legends into one.

Comment: Yeah the other issues is that second plot's gridlines overlay the first plot, so as I see you plotted them without grid

Comment: But i wonder if there is a way to add it to prev plots.. coz Time total and Time productive is also combo of two separate plots

Comment: Time total and time productive are on same axis but score is on different axis.